# How to get uri from Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have .png files in `ListViev`, so if someone click on one of them I whant to navigate to other page and send `Uri` of this file, so I'm doing that this way:

```
    private void GifList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView element = sender as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView;
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image clipArt = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image();
        clipArt = element.SelectedItem as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image;
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource imagePath = clipArt.Source;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), imagePath);
    }
```

On breakpoint I can see that `imagePath` include path to my file, but how to acces it? same `iamgePath.ToString()` returns `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` how can I acces path to that file?

Answer (score 0):

Clipart.Source is a BitmapImage so you need to get ((BitmapImage)Clipart.Source).UriSource to get the Uri or ((BitmapImage)Clipart.Source).UriSource.AbsolutePath (or AbsoluteUri) to get a path string.